# Open Refine IF statement

Tags: if-statement, openrefine

I have a question about Open Refine's `IF` statement `GREL`. I have two columns,  one is "Address" and the other is "House Code". I'd like to create an If-Then statement that would say something like:

```
IF("Address", "Building D", 1004)
```

So, if the address is "Building D", the second column "House Code" would return 1004. While I know that this is very easy to accomplish in Excel, I haven't found the correct `GREL` equation yet...

I would appreciate any help...

Answer (score 1):

The logic of [an `if` in OpenRefine](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Controls#ifexpression-o-expression-etrue-expression-efalse) is about the same as in Excel: if(condition, what to do if the condition is true, what to do if the condition is false).

In your case you could create the column "House code" with this Grel formula:

```
if(value=="Building C", "1004", null)
```

As a reminder, `value` is a variable that refers to the contents of each cell in your column.

Demo :

[image]

If the "House code" column already exists, you can transform it with this formula :

```
if(cells.Adress.value=="Building C", "1004", null)
```

Demo :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for. Not totally used to GREL, but I love Open Refine and plan to use it a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. If no better answer occurs in the next days, do not forget to accept this one. ;)